# Getting data from curl but same with axios giving an empty object

Tags: reactjs, curl, axios

I am using react axios to get data from a backend flask api server. When I do curl, I am getting perfect data as response but when I try with axios, I getting an empty object with 200

I have tried many possible ways in which we do axios (might be missing the right one)

curl `curl -X GET "http://10.214.79.37:5050/v1/vision/api/assets/search"  -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"barraOnly\": true, \"label\": \"AAPL\", \"missingId\": false, \"searchFilter\": [], \"source\": null}"`

axios code below

```
const apiUrl = 'http://10.214.79.37:5050/v1/vision/api/assets/search';


const SearchTicker = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState('');
    const handleInputChange = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setState(event.target.value)
        axios.get(
            apiUrl, { data: "{ \"barraOnly\": true, \"label\": \"AAPL\", \"missingId\": false, \"searchFilter\": [], \"source\": null}"},           
            {headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}},
            ).then(function (response) {console.log(response)});
        // console.log(resp.data);
    }
```

Edit: After taking your inputs, I have updated the code (below) still not getting the data. Cane there be a issue with API itself specific to browser calls ?

```
const apiUrl = 'http://10.214.79.37:5050/v1/vision/api/assets/search';

    const SearchTicker = () => {
        const [state, setState] = useState('');
        const handleInputChange = event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            setState(event.target.value)

            const header = { 
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            };

            const param = { 
              barraOnly: true, 
              label: "AAPL",
              missingId: false, 
              searchFilter: [], 
              source: null,
            };

            axios
              .get(apiUrl, { params:param , headers: header},)
              .then(response => console.log(response))
          };
```

edit2: By debugging the backend I realized that the params are not getting into the api. Not sure why

Comment: Are you getting any error? Check your console.

Comment: no error at all

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using `async` but not `await`, try to add `await` which `pauses` execution untill you get data from request,

```
const apiUrl = 'http://10.214.79.37:5050/v1/vision/api/assets/search';


const SearchTicker = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState('');
    const handleInputChange = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setState(event.target.value)
        let response = await axios.get(apiUrl, { data: "{ \"barraOnly\": true, \"label\": \"AAPL\", \"missingId\": false, \"searchFilter\": [], \"source\": null}"},           
            {headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}});
        console.log(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that i want to add here:
1. Since you are not awaiting on anything, you do not need to mark your function as async.

2. `GET` method of axios does not support data and is not intended to send body along with the request. The good practice will be to update your api handle to accept `POST`. Anyways if its not possible to change the api, you can send your data by wrapping it inside params object as suggested by axios itself.

```
axios.get(url,{params: {your data}, {header:{}});
```

Try something like this.
Hope it helps!!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve the issue using POST as I realized that even after using params, Flask API server is not taking the data parameters. I updated the API to receive POST and it worked like a charm. 
Thanks for your help.